# aws-sdk-go-v2 custom logger

Tags: go, logrus, aws-sdk-go-v2

With v1 of the SDK i could use logrus for my custom logger, like:

```
    Logger: aws.LoggerFunc(func(args ...interface{}) {
        log.WithField("process", "s3").Debug(args...)
    }),
```

This has changed with sdk v2, https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/configuring-sdk/logging/

It seems i need to use logging.logger as per https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config#WithLogger

I'm having a hard time using logrus for this purpose, can anyone suggest what i need to do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that sdk v2 offers a [func wrapper](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/smithy-go/logging#LoggerFunc) to satisfy **logging.logger**:

```golang
import (
   ...
   "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
   "github.com/aws/smithy-go/logging"
   log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    
    logger := logging.LoggerFunc(func(classification logging.Classification, format string, v ...interface{}) {
        // your custom logging 
        log.WithField("process", "s3").Debug(v...)
    })

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(
        context.TODO(),
        ...
        config.WithLogger(logger),
    )
    ....
}
```

Comment: that's the missing link, smithy. I think syntax in how to satisfy something is also a bit tricky. Thanks!